# Warning: Overfull \hbox in table

Tags: tables, warnings

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand*\mc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{Eleverne fra $9$.~#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\def\spc{\hspace{0.8em}}
\centering
 \caption{Something.}
 \label{tbl:1}
  \begin{tabular}{
           S[table-format = 2.1]
    >{\spc}S[table-format = 2]
           S[table-format = 3]
    >{\spc}S[table-format = 2]
           S[table-format = 3]
  }
   \toprule
    {S{\o}vnm{\ae}ngde} & \mc{A} & \mc{B}          \\
   \midrule
    \si{\hour} & {Abs.} & {Rel.} & {Abs.} & {Rel.} \\
   \midrule
     6.5       &  1\spc &   4    &  0\spc &   0    \\
     7         &  4\spc &  16    &  2\spc &  10    \\
     7.5       &  3\spc &  12    &  3\spc &  15    \\
     8         &  8\spc &  32    &  9\spc &  45    \\
     8.5       &  5\spc &  20    &  3\spc &  15    \\
     9         &  2\spc &   8    &  3\spc &  15    \\
     9.5       &  1\spc &   4    &  0\spc &   0    \\
    10         &  1\spc &   4    &  0\spc &   0    \\
   \midrule
               & 25\spc & 100    & 20\spc & 100    \\
   \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

I get the following warning:

```
Overfull \hbox (8.00003pt too wide) detected at line
```

for lines 27--36.

How do I get rit of these without changing the output layout in the table?

Comment: What's the use of `\spc`?

Comment: You are not reserving any space for your spaces! What are they for anyway?

Comment: @egreg To move the second and third column of data to the right (to center them relative to "Eleverne fra 9. A"), and the forth and fifth column of data to center them relative to "Eleverne fra 9. B".

Comment: @JosephWright See comment to egreg.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's better to increase the size of the items in the second header row:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand*\mc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{Eleverne fra $9$.~#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Something.}
\label{tbl:1}
\begin{tabular}{
  S[table-format = 2.1]
  S[table-format = 2]
  S[table-format = 3]
  S[table-format = 2]
  S[table-format = 3]
}
\toprule
{Søvnmængde} & \mc{A} & \mc{B}          \\
\midrule
\si{\hour} & {\quad Abs.\quad} & {\quad Rel.\quad} & {\quad Abs.\quad} & {\quad Rel.\quad} \\
\midrule
 6.5 &  1 &   4 &  0 &   0 \\
 7   &  4 &  16 &  2 &  10 \\
 7.5 &  3 &  12 &  3 &  15 \\
 8   &  8 &  32 &  9 &  45 \\
 8.5 &  5 &  20 &  3 &  15 \\
 9   &  2 &   8 &  3 &  15 \\
 9.5 &  1 &   4 &  0 &   0 \\
10   &  1 &   4 &  0 &   0 \\
\midrule
     & 25 & 100 & 20 & 100 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]